# Why does my "ls -a-l /home" not work?

Tags: command-line, ls

```
Marias-MacBook-Air:~ mariasharapova$ ls -a /home
.   ..

Marias-MacBook-Air:~ mariasharapova$ ls -a-1 /home
ls: illegal option -- -
usage: ls [-ABCFGHLOPRSTUWabcdefghiklmnopqrstuwx1] [file ...]

Marias-MacBook-Air:~ mariasharapova$ ls -a-l /home
ls: illegal option -- -
usage: ls [-ABCFGHLOPRSTUWabcdefghiklmnopqrstuwx1] [file ...]
```

Comment: Try `ls -a1` and `ls -al`. I tried this on two systems (Linux and NetBSD) and it worked.

Comment: I found the answer.  I was typing ls -a-l without a space.  If I don't want to use space, I take the minus out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have a space between `-a` and `-1`, so `ls` is trying to interpret the `-` as an option, not as signifying an option. Add a space, or just use `ls -a1` and it should work properly. Although I have to admit, `-1` seems a rather unusual option - I usually `ls -al` as opposed to `ls -a1`.

Comment: `-1` is good option to use if you want to list all files in a single column but not long listing.

Answer (score 3):

`ls -a -l` is what you meant. Unix arguments must be space separated or combined into a single argument, as in `ls -al`. In fairness, your style would be legal on the DOS prompt, where you don't need spaces before `/`-delimited options (e.g., `DIR/D/B` is fine). But Unix is not DOS... fortunately.

Answer (score 2):

To combine two options simply do: 

```
ls -al /home
```

 Or, if you really want to use one dash for each option do it this way: 

```
ls -a -l /home
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate the options by a space.  If you want to combine the options, you should remove the dash from the second option.  So, you should say `ls -a -l` or `ls -al` but you cannot say `ls -a-l`.

Comment: Thanks everyone!  Why don't the ticks stay green when I tick your answers?

Comment: You can only select one "correct / accepted" answer, Maria. That's not to say there won't be multiple correct answers given, but there can only be one "accepted". You can "upvote" the helpful answers (more than one if you're so inclined) by clicking on the graphical up arrow.